# How to embed UISlider in UITabBar?

Tags: iphone

I want to put slider in tabbar.
Is there anyway to embed UISlider in UITabBar?

Comment: Why not just put a UISlider on the bottom of the screen? Embedding a slider in a TabBar seems pointless unless the TabBar is going to be 2x high.

Comment: I want to put buttons and slider in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to put a `UISlider` in a `IUTabBar`. However, you can add one to a `UIToolBar`, which is probably what you mean to do.

Read up on the [documentation for `UIToolBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html), specifically the method `setItems:animated:`:

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Can I put only text button in UIToolbar? Can i put image button and text below button in UIToolbar?

Comment: You can put any subclass of `UIView` onto a `UIToolBar`, including `UITextField`, `UIBarButton`, `UISlider`, etc. In the IB, just drag and drop.